# Chrome driver crashing on start up with traps error

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using Selenium Python with Chrome webdriver for web scraping. In the last few days, I have noticed that the server stops responding with the below error. I was having Chrome driver version 83.0.4103.14 in the server. I have tried updating Chrome browser and webdriver to the latest version 88.0.4324.27, but still the error is happening. Can you please help me to fix this issue

[4798.122960] traps: chromedriver[2957] trap int3 ip:5610299105ec sp:7ffdbf97c8c0 error:0 in chromedriver[56102965f000+723000]

Comment: i am getting the same error on chrome version and driver version 99 , with amazon ec2 .. was there a solution discovered ?

Answer (score 0):

check your chrome driver version and matching version of chrome released

chrome driver version 89.0.4389.23 is beta version

try download Latest stable release: [ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.96/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have replaced the beta version with the stable version, however the issue still happening. I have edited the original post with version of Chrome webdriver (88.0.4324.27) that I have used.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue reproducible with different versions of the chromedriver. Apparently it was triggered by the memory limit, in our case the resource.setrlimit in the python wrapper for chromedriver.

Increasing the limit fixed the problem.